# How to expand space between RecyclerView Item while scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, recyclerview-layout

How to expand space between `recyclerview` item while scrolling as shown below. I tried to add a custom animation in `onBindViewHolder` method but this solution doesn't work as I want. It looks like some animation add to `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.onScrolled` method. Any idea? Thx.

[image: Custom animation]

Comment: did you get the solution? I also wanted to implement the same.

Comment: no, I didn't :(

Comment: If you have any idea then, please share it.

Comment: ok no problem, I will be remember

Answer (score 0):

One thing we can do is hiding and showing a transparent view below ItemLayout onSrcoll

```
var scrollListener = object : OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                (list.adapter as CustomAdapter).changeState(newState)
            }
        }
```

and in Adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if(state == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
            holder.view.visibility = View.GONE
        }else{
            holder.view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    fun changeState(newState: Int) {
        state = newState
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```